# dynamic query on entity field name in a generic

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I'm using generics because I need a lot of reusability with different types of data. my main problem is querying data. I'm looking for a way to query something like this:

```
public void test<T>(int id, T type) where T : class
{
    using (var ctx = myDbContext())
    {
        var myTbl = ctx.Set<T>();
        //this line gets the primary key of the table
        string key = myTbl.GetPrimaryKey(ctx);

        //this is the query I want:
        var myResult = myTbl.FirstOrDefault(x => x.key == id);

        //let's say if key = "UserId", then (x => x.UserId == id) or something that translates to this.
    }
}
```

also I have implemented following method:

```
public object GetPropertyValue(object src, string propertyName)
```

that I can use to get value of a specific property.

but my problem is that I can't use it inside the .FirstOrDefault() call because of the LINQ to query issues with methods.

I currently use this code instead:

```
var myResult = myTbl.ToList().FirstOrDefault(x => (int)GetPropertyValue(x, key) == id);
```

which is fine with a few number of rows in database, but when data grows in future it will have a lot of performance impact.

P.S: I'm using EF power tools for reverse engineering code first

Comment: Umm, your code sample is completely unclear. Please, atleast provide correct variable names, because now I don't even know where you use 'key' variable.

Comment: @eocron edited. the 'key' variable currently is passed to the 'GetPropertyValue()' method.

Comment: PS i hope you have moved away from the code above since...pattern look bad and bad practice ie your not using the framework in a gd way. you will get poor performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First -> Dont use `myTbl.ToList().FirstOrDefault(x => (int)GetPropertyValue(x, key) == id)` because it generates a select that brings all rows from that table, then filter by id in memory. You should translate your filter to an Expression> that will generare a select filtered by the Id column.

Build your linq expression like this:

```
var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");

string keyPropName = type.GetPrimaryKey(ctx);
var equalExp = Expression.Equal(
    Expression.Property(x, keyPropName),
    Expression.Constant(id)
    );

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equalExp, x); //x => x.Id == idValue

var myResult = myTbl.FirstOrDefault(lambda);
```

I used your `GetPropertyValue` and `GetPrimaryKey` methods.

Comment: nice approach, but I think you missed 'id' parameter, instead of `Expression.Constant(GetPropertyValue(type, keyPropName))` I use `Expression.Constant(id)`

Comment: That is right!!, I didnt look at that parameter. Sorry, I will change the answer.

Comment: what is tbl here and dont say the table i know that but if you had that then the whole query is pointless

Comment: @Seabizkit, tbl is the `Set<T>` in the question called `myTbl`. The set is instantiated like this: `var myTbl = ctx.Set<T>();`. It is my mystake to do not use the same variable name. I updated the answer.

Comment: @AlejandroPérezFals thanks! that is what i thought. if you have `ctx.Set<T>();` then you should of been able to just type where on myTbl, making the Expression obsolete ...? looking at this makes me think there should be an easier way, maybe show your usage. I was writing expressions against `ctx.Set(type);` and not `ctx.Set<T>();` so mine required more thought. Trying to picture your usage, for when you would want to do this.

Comment: also sorry i see that it does say in the original question now.

Answer (score 1):

Umm, your code sample is completely unclear. Please, atleast provide correct variable names, because now I don't even know where you use 'key' variable.

Also, if you want to store and query objects and it's properties of various inheritance and nestings, consider to use NoSQL databases instead of relation based SQL engines.